# Inconsistent WAR deployment on Websphere server

Tags: java, maven, websphere, war

I'm not sure as how to formulate this question as I guess it's pretty vague. My issue is that I want to deploy a module on a Websphere server. I generate my war file using Maven (mvn clean package) as do my colleagues. Thing is, the wars I'm generating are not working and theirs do. Server logs print something related to some static files that couldn't be read in the package.

Tried comparing my war package to some other that works using a diff viewer (Beyond Compare to be precise) and it doesn't show any difference between .war contents (even comparing binary) but one war deploys fine and the other doesn't.

It does show though changes between the packages (not comparing content files individually) in size and hex content but can't pinpoint what could these changes be.

We're using the same Maven, OS and Java versions. Also, we're deploying the module the same way. Right now, I'm copying my changes inside a war file I know works and deploying it that way.

Any pointers as to what could the cause be? What these changes between .war packages could be attributed to?

Error shown on logs:

- Unable to process file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/xxxx/image.png

Afterwards, module deploys fine but has trouble reading files from it (can't request static files such as css, images, js, etc.).

Comment: Did you try to remove cache/temporary files and folders from websphere and redeploy war file?

Comment: What operating system are you running WebSphere on? What operating system are you building your WAR on? Is it the same as your colleague's that is working?

Comment: Can you look at the deployed war after it's expanded and see what all the files & directories & permissions are?

Comment: So to answer these questions: I cleaned temporary files. Websphere OS seems to be UNIX judging by file paths (server is managed, can't access it aside from the web console). I'm building my WAR on Windows.

Comment: Ok. But if you can't get somebody to look at the deployed files on the filesystem, this might be a lot more difficult to track down. Are you able to successfully deploy the colleagues' wars, and they fail to deploy yours? Are they all on Windows too?

Comment: Use the "jar tf warFileName" command to list the entries in each WAR file.  Redirect the output to a file.  Sort the file.  Then compare the output generated from the 2 WARs.

Comment: @dbreaux yes to both questions. I can desploy colleagues wars (in fact, I'm deploying my changes by copying my files inside another war that I know works and deploying that). Everyone uses Windows.

Comment: @jblye I'll try that, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: The things that come to mind at this point are local file permissions (but probably not since you can copy into an existing war), character encodings, linefeeds. When you copy into an existing war, are you overlaying every single file? Or leaving some subset of them intact?

Comment: Every single file. Both wars have identical files, no content changes between them.

Comment: Also @jblye: tried it. Both files are identical.